# YouTube API search list_next() throws UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube-api

When I feed a non-English string into the YouTube API library's
search, it only works during the initial search. If I call list_next(),
it throws a UnicodeEncodeError.

When I use a simple ascii string, everything works correctly.

Any suggestions about what I should do?

Here's a simplified code of what I'm doing:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import apiclient.discovery

def test(query):
    youtube = apiclient.discovery.build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey='xxx')
    ys = youtube.search()
    req = ys.list(
        q=query.encode('utf-8'),
        type='video',
        part='id,snippet',
        maxResults=50
    )
    while (req):
        res = req.execute()
        for i in res['items']:
            print(i['id']['videoId'])
        req = ys.list_next(req, res)

test(u'한글')
test(u'日本語')
test(u'\uD55C\uAE00')
test(u'\u65E5\u672C\u8A9E')
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\prj\scripts\yt\search.py", line 316, in _search
    req = ys.list_next(req, res)
  File "D:\Apps\Python\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 966, in methodNext
    parsed[4] = urlencode(newq)
  File "D:\Apps\Python\lib\urllib.py", line 1343, in urlencode
    v = quote_plus(str(v))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Versions:

- google-api-python-client (1.6.2)
- Python 2.7.13 (Win32)

**EDIT: I posted a workaround below.**

Comment: What is the value of `q=query.encode('utf-8')`? This may be the cause of your error.

Comment: Unicode strings typed in the source file encoded in utf-8 with the "coding: utf-8" header. For example:


    test(u'한글')
    test(u'日本語')


I've also tried the escaped versions:


    test(u'\uD55C\uAE00')
    test(u'\u65E5\u672C\u8A9E')


Both do work correctly up to the first execute(), but then I get the error when I call list_next() for the next page.

Comment: I couldn't format my comment above correctly, so I added the example to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is interested, here's one workaround that works for me:

```
googleapiclient/discovery.py:
(old) q = parse_qsl(parsed[4])
(new) q = parse_qsl(parsed[4].encode('ascii'))
```

Explanation

In discovery.py, list_next() parses and unescapes the previous url, then makes a new url from it:

```
pageToken = previous_response['nextPageToken']
parsed = list(urlparse(request.uri))
q = parse_qsl(parsed[4])

# Find and remove old 'pageToken' value from URI
newq = [(key, value) for (key, value) in q if key != 'pageToken']
newq.append(('pageToken', pageToken))
parsed[4] = urlencode(newq)
uri = urlunparse(parsed)
```

It seems the problem is when parse_qsl unescapes the unicode parsed[4], it
returns the utf-8 encoded value in a unicode type. urlencode does not like
this:

```
q = urlparse.parse_qsl(u'q=%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80')
[(u'q', u'\xed\x95\x9c\xea\xb8\x80')]
urllib.urlencode(q)
UnicodeEncodeError
```

If parse_qsl is given a plain ascii string, it returns a plain utf-8 encoded string which urlencode likes:

```
q = urlparse.parse_qsl(u'q=%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80'.encode('ascii'))
[('q', '\xed\x95\x9c\xea\xb8\x80')]
urllib.urlencode(q)
'q=%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80'
```